# Issues with OAuth Authentication in LinkedIn API

Tags: coldfusion, oauth, coldfusion-9

I'm working on a LinkedIn library for a client of mine, and am having some trouble getting through the authorization piece of the puzzle.  I used the OAuth library on RIAForge and rewrote everything in order to utilize script based CFCs in CF9 and MXUnit testing.  When I try to create the OAuth signature using the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm, I can never seem to match what LinkedIn is looking for.  He is my method to sign the request I have:

```
  public void function signRequest(any req){
    var params = Arguments.req.getAllParameters();
    var secret = "#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(getConsumer().getConsumerSecret())#&#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(Arguments.req.getOAuthSecret())#";
    var base = '';

    params = Variables.encoder.encodedParameter(params, true, true);
    secret = JavaCast('string', secret).getBytes();

    local.mac = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.Mac').getInstance('HmacSHA1');
    local.key = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec').init(secret, local.mac.getAlgorithm());

    base = reReplaceNoCase(Arguments.req.getRequestUrl(), 'http[s]?://', '/');
    params = listSort(params, 'text', 'asc', '&');
    base = JavaCast('string', "#base#&#params#").getBytes();

    local.mac.init(local.key);
    local.mac.update(base);

    Arguments.req.addParameter('oauth_signature', toBase64(mac.doFinal()), true);
  }
```

The issue, I believe is in the secret key for the encryption. I have compared the base string to the OAuth testing tool from LinkedIn, http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/oauth-test/, and it matches perfectly, so the key used to encrypt it must me the problem. I don't have the OAuth token secret yet, so my secret is something similar to `fdsa43fdsa3j&`. Is that what it should be, or should the ampersand at the end be in encoded format, or something else?

**Correct Method**

```
  public void function signRequest(any req){
    var params = Arguments.req.getAllParameters();
    var secret = "#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(getConsumer().getConsumerSecret())#&#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(Arguments.req.getOAuthSecret())#";
    var base = '';

    params = Variables.encoder.encodedParameter(params, true, true);
    secret = toBinary(toBase64(secret));

    local.mac = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.Mac').getInstance('HmacSHA1');
    local.key = createObject('java', 'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec').init(secret, local.mac.getAlgorithm());

    base = "#Arguments.req.getMethod()#&";
    base = base & Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(Arguments.req.getRequestUrl());
    params = listSort(params, 'text', 'asc', '&');
    base = "#base#&#Variables.encoder.parameterEncodedFormat(params)#";

    local.mac.init(local.key);
    local.mac.update(JavaCast('string', base).getBytes());
    //writeDump(toString(toBase64(mac.doFinal()))); abort;
    Arguments.req.addParameter('oauth_signature', toString(toBase64(mac.doFinal())), true);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ben Nadel has an example](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1971-Authenticating-Twilio-Request-Signatures-Using-ColdFusion-And-HMAC-SHA1-Hashing.htm) for using OAuth for connecting to Twilio. The major difference between your signing code and his is that he uses some encodings when setting up his SecretKeySpec.

Here is the relevant snip from his post:

```
<cfset secretKeySpec = createObject(
    "java",
    "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec"
  ).init(
    toBinary( toBase64( twilioAuthKey ) ),
    "HmacSHA1"
  )
/>
```

Comment: Thanks Pat, I can tell that this is going to hold my answer because when I go to Ben Nadel's page, my picture came up ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It wasn't necessarily the 100% correct answer, but it moved me in the proper direction. I've posted the correct method above, so that it will hopefully help others.

Comment: @DaveLong: You should post that as a separate answer and accept it rather than modifying your question. This will act as a signpost for future readers. Alternatively, edit Patrick's answer to match the solution you used so that he can retain the "accept" credit.